# How to execute the following command line expression from java code?

Tags: java, macos, unix, command-line, saucelabs

I am using Mac and I am trying to run the below command using java code to activate the Sauce connection to connect with sauce lab

```
bin/sc -u "username" -k "ACCESS KEY"
```

I have to run this inside a specific folder, imagine my folder is located inside

```
/Users/username/Documents/sc-4.5.4-osx
```

but i am getting below exception when I run the code

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/Users/username/Documents/sc-4.5.4-osx": error=13, Permission denied

including the code below

```
String[] command = { "/Users/username/Documents/sc-4.5.4-osx", "bin/sc -u username -k accesskey" };    
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("tunnel started");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need the first String in the command array to be the executable itself. Try specifying it as this: `String[] command = { "/Users/username/Documents/sc-4.5.4-osx/bin/sc", "-uusername", "-kaccesskey" }; `

Comment: ok now there is no exception and I think it is running, I have one more doubt, is there a way we can visually see or get response of what's happening when we execute the command? looks like command is executed but still the sauce connect is not active so I want to debug by looking into the command line response.. thanks for the help Mcarlin

Comment: The `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` returns a [Process object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) which has methods to get the output stream and error stream. From there you can read the output from the process.

Comment: thank you MCarlin,, I will try that

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the first String in the command array to be the executable itself, while each additional element is an argument for the command. As @Gordon Davisson pointed out, this String[] is expected to be in the post-parsing form. Right now it's trying to execute the directory which won't work. Try specifying it as this:

`String[] command = { "/Users/username/Documents/sc-4.5.4-osx/bin/sc", "-uusername", "-kaccesskey" };`

**EDIT 1**
Add more info regarding args (Thanks @GordonDavisson)

Comment: Another thing to note here is that each argument is passed as a separate (string) element of the array, rather than space-separated (and maybe quote-wrapped) as they'd be on a command line. Normally, the shell takes a single string, splits it on spaces, parses and removes quotes, etc, and generates the argument list from that. Here, we're passing the raw argument list, so it has to be in post-parsing rather than pre-parsing form.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @GordonDavisson